# Can I use the spaCy command line tools to train an NER model containing an additional entity type?

Tags: spacy

I am trying to train spaCy models using just the [`python -m spacy train`](https://spacy.io/api/cli#train) command line tool [without writing any code of my own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921513/managing-train-develop-splits-with-the-spacy-command-line-trainer).

I have a training set of documents to which I have added `OIL_COMPANY` entity spans. I used [`gold.docs_to_json`](https://spacy.io/api/goldparse#docs_to_json) to create training files in the [JSON-serializable format](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#json-input).

I can train starting from an empty model. However, if I try to extend the existing `en_core_web_lg` model I see the following error.

```
KeyError: "[E022] Could not find a transition with the name 'B-OIL_COMPANY' in the NER model."
```

So I need to be able to tell the command line tool to add `OIL_COMPANY` to an existing list of NER labels. The discussion in [Training an additional entity type](https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-new-entity-type) shows how to do this in code by calling [`add_label`](https://spacy.io/api/entityrecognizer#add_label) on the NER pipeline, but I don't see any command line option that does this.

Is it possible to extend an existing NER model to new entities with just the command line training tools, or do I have to write code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ines [answered this](https://support.prodi.gy/t/prodigy-ner-batch-train-vs-spacy-train/1665/11) for me on the Prodigy support forum.

> I think what's happening here is that the spacy train command expects
>   the base model you want to update to already have all labels added
>   that you want to train. (It processes the data as a stream, so it's
>   not going to compile all labels upfront and silently add them on the
>   fly.) So if you want to update an existing pretrained model and add a
>   new label, you should be able to just add the label and save out the
>   base model:

```
ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner") ner.add_label("YOUR_LABEL")
nlp.to_disk("./base-model")
```

This isn't quite writing no code but it's pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://spacy.io/api/cli) link for the CLI in spaCy.

> Train a model. Expects data in spaCy’s `JSON format`. On each epoch, a model will be saved out to the directory. Accuracy scores and model details will be added to a `meta.json` to allow packaging the model using the `package` command.

```
python -m spacy train [lang] [output_path] [train_path] [dev_path]
[--base-model] [--pipeline] [--vectors] [--n-iter] [--n-early-stopping]
[--n-examples] [--use-gpu] [--version] [--meta-path] [--init-tok2vec]
[--parser-multitasks] [--entity-multitasks] [--gold-preproc] [--noise-level]
[--orth-variant-level] [--learn-tokens] [--textcat-arch] [--textcat-multilabel]
[--textcat-positive-label] [--verbose]
```